# AngularJs - Should I destroy a directive instance manually?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

Consider an application that utilizes `ngRepeat` to show a list of directive instances.

When an element is removed from the list, should I manually destroy the directive instance or is it safe enough to call `splice()` on the array that holds the element?

The developer guide is not very helpful here.

Comment: I'm guessing that is safe, but why would you want to manually destroy the instance? Why not use `ngRepeat` with a filter?

Comment: I'm thinking more about memory and performance issues.

Comment: Splicing a referenced object from an array doesn't destroy it, right?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by _destroy the directive instance_? `ngRepeat` doesn't create multiple instances of a directive, if you mean that. There's only one instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are in doubt and want to check whether the directive is actually getting destroyed, you could put a watch on `$destroy` in your directive. For example:

```
// inside your link function
scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
    console.log("destroyed");
});
```

Comment: I have no idea why I didn't came up with that.

Comment: FYI: They get destroyed